Why is Tocloft shifting my ToC-title?
In my report I increased the margins with the geometry package.
Afterwards i implemented Tocloft into my document to create dots between Chapter/section-title and pagenumber. This works fine.
But by including Tocloft the Caption Contents is shifted down (compared to other chapter Captions). If i exclude Tocloft or define it for the titles the points between Chaptername and pagenumber are gone.
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,titlepage]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[a4paper,left=35mm,right=25mm,width=150mm,top=25mm,bottom=20mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr} % fancy heade
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{tocloft} %<- enable/disable 
%\renewcommand{\cftpartleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}} %<- enable/disable 
%\renewcommand{\cftchapleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}} %<- enable/ disable 
%\renewcommand{\cftsecleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}}  %<- enable/disable 

\pagestyle{fancy}
\titleformat{\chapter}
[hang] %shape (see titlesec package documentation)
{\vspace{-3cm}\bfseries\Huge} %size of chapter font
{\thechapter}
{20pt} % distance between number and title
{} 
[]

\fancyhead{}
\fancyhead[R]{\thepage}
\fancyhead[L]{\nouppercase{\leftmark}}
\fancyfoot{}



\begin{document}
 \chapter*{Abstract}

\newpage
\tableofcontents    
\chapter{Test}
\lipsum
\end{document}       

In this miniversion you can see both outcomes by including/excluding toloft and the outcommented part.

Can someone help me by presenting a solution how to keep the dots between the pagenumber and titles and the right positioning of Contents?

Does this MWE compile for you without error? Because it does not for me, there is something missing for \titleformat

When I add the last mandatory argument for \titleformat (I just left it blank). I see no formatting differences with and without tocloft. Are you by any change on OverLeaf? We sadly see a lot of OL users ignoring compilation errors.

Thank you for your quick response. I have updated the MWE. Now it should be working.

What is that \vspace doing in the arg for chapter font size? It should not go there. There is a separate interface (AFAIR) for setting the spacings.

You still need the titles option for tocloft otherwise it is not compatible with titlesec. Use \titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{-3cm}{0pt} to set the spacing.

In general, if you see your self using \vspace for anything other than designing a title page, you're probably doing something wrong.

Thank you very much. That worked perfectly.

As mentioned from @daleif the answer is:
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{-3cm}{0pt}

Including the previous line and excluding the
\vspace

